# JvectorMap Trim data output

Tags: javascript, json, trim, jvectormap

I'm using JvectorMap to map carriers by state for easy editing the json data looks like this:

```
 {
"states": {
    "2015": {
        "US-AK": [" Aenta", " Assurant", "     ", "         ", "           ", "     ", "       "],
        "US-AL": [" Aenta", " Assurant", "     ", "         ", " Goden Rule", "     ", " Humana"],
        "US-AR": [" Aenta", " Assurant", "     ", "         ", "           ", "     ", "       "],
        "US-AZ": [" Aenta", "         ", "     ", "         ", " Goden Rule", "     ", " Humana"],
        "US-CA": [" Aenta", " Assurant", "     ", "         ", "           ", "     ", "       "],
          }
        }
    }
```

The code that renders the map is this:

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON('../js/medicalOff.json', function(data){
    var val = 2015;
        statesValues = jvm.values.apply({}, jvm.values(data.states));
  $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'us_merc_en',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        regionStyle: {
            initial:{
         fill: '#87c9b4',   
        },
            hover:{
             fill:'#2e8f70',   
            },
        },
onRegionTipShow: function(e, label, code) {
var str =  data.states[val][code];
var trim = str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
 label.html('<b>' + label.html() + '</b>' + '<br> ' + trim);
},
  });
});
});
```

Before I added `var str =  data.states[val][code]; var trim = str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");` the data came out like `Texas: ,,,Assurant,,,Humana`. Now I'm not very good at JavaScript but I have a basic understanding of it.  Currently I get "Undefined is not a function" error.  What would be the correct way to implement this part

```
var str =  data.states[val][code];
var trim = str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the line that has the error is `var trim = str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");`. If I am assuming correctly then that means `str` is not a string, but rather some other object.

In a case like this, you need to inspect **"If it's not a string, what is `str`?"**

One way to inspect is to `alert(str)` and see what pops up. Place the alert line directly before the line that has the error.

Of course `alert(str)` is the same as `alert(data.states[val][code])`. You may find help by using `alert(JSON.stringify(data.states[val][code]))` or `alert(JSON.stringify(data.states[val]))`.

Comment: Upon taking your advice `alert(str)` returns `Aetna, Assurant,  ,  ,  ` where as `alert(JSON.stringify(data.states[val][code]))` returns `["Aetna","Assurant"," "," ", " " ]`. So does that mean it is not a string but rather an array? If so that would mean I have to concantenate it right?

Comment: Great! Yes that is an array. I would rename `str` to `arr`, and then you can enter a new line `var str = arr.join(", ")` which creates a string using `, ` as the separator. Actually you can use whichever separator you desire.

Comment: You may wish to adjust your regular expression, something like `str.replace(/^[, ]+|[, ]+$|[, ]+(?=,)/g, "")` would be more effective at removing empty entries. This one will remove both spaces and commas `[, ]`, it will remove multiple/unlimited `+`, and it will also remove extra commas from within the middle `[, ]+(?=,)` so long as at least one comma is preserved. `(?=,)`

Comment: By the way, Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you for helping me through this and for the welcome! It is definitely a cool place to learn from your peers!